PCB Beginner Schematic Check
new to PCB design and wanted to learn by doing. I have linked a schematic to a project I am working on. This is a single piece of a larger project which will hopefully work nicely together but wanted to do it piece by piece for debugging purposes. Kindly asking if some of the experts could provide any insight or if they see any issues with how I am setting it up. Thanks in advance!


Please ask a specific question

Major hint to beginners when doing schematic captures and layout design: follow the datasheets, integration/design guides, and application notes. Since we don't know your specific application, there's really no way to know if your design is correct. Your schematic appears to be well readable and easy to follow so good job on that.

It's unclear what the device must do and with what specs to determine if the schematics can do it. Also the screeshot is likely saved as jpg as the image quality is really blurry so it is impossible to read small text without guessing. Also most of the components are unknown, we cannot guess if 22pF caps are correct for your 32768 Hz RTC crystal, as it sounds absurdly high value, and from the schematics we cannot determine if the MCU pins are correct, so we would have to dig out the data sheet of the MCU to see if those are RTC crystal pins. Battery will fully drain without protection.

My theory is that people who start out on the coding side naturally gravitate towards the "mini subcircuits connected by net labels" style of schematic layout because it is a parallel to functions interacting though variables. However, when asking people (especially people who are not familiar with the circuit) to look at your schematic and "debug" it, it becomes a game of hunt-the-label, and - outside of a CAD program - it's hard to be sure you've found all the instances. For readability, I find it's better to connect things explicitly, unless the alternative is an illegible mess.

@vir The problem with explicit connections is that more often than not it does become an illegible mess. You can make it relatively easy to point out where buses and tracks go by some judicial notes on the schematic and making sure you put related components together on each sheet.
My big issues with this are that it's too small/low rez to read and the symbols aren't very well thought out.

Min sub circuit methodology is rubbish. It's rubbish because you haven't yet grasped how much a full proper schematic can reveal to the more expert reader hence you think you can treat blocks like code. When you draw a schematic like this you are handicapping the better engineers from helping you and they lose interest (because they've seen it before and know they are likely to waste their time) and, it's case of levelling down to the weakest engineer's capacity to understand. In short, use schematic wires to make connections and layout the schematic as if you were laying out a PCB.

For interest, what will it be used for. The wireless module caught my attention.

Thanks for the comments. Definitely could have provided some more insight and understand that schematics even smallish ones aren't necessarily obvious to just look at especially when using the net labels. Appreciate the helpful comments again not PCB designer basically just whipped it up and wanted to see if there were any obvious issues before sending it to a board shop.
